# How to Allow third-party cookies from karate-config.js file

Tags: automation, karate, third-party-cookies

I have a few features that are not working because the Third-party cookies are blocking them. Can we enable it from the karate-config.js file?

1. Allow sites to save and read cookie data (recommended)
2. Block third-party cookies (Default)

This is how we initialize the karate driver.

```js
karate.configure('driver',  {
    type:  browser,
    addOptions: [ '--disable-popup-blocking', '--disable-notifications' ]
});
```

I'm expecting to enable the third-party cookies using karate.

**Update**

This is from selenium/python, I want to replicate it on karate:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.block_third_party_cookies": False})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: no idea, is it possible for you to point to a public page where this problem can be replicated ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but I edited the question to show an example from another framework.

Comment: would be great if you can do a little investigation as to how that python framework does it. also are you sure you are referring to chrome and not chromedriver ? there's a difference. see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+chrome+options+chromedriver

Comment: I will investigate more. A was referring to Chromedriver. Thank you.